# Flutterflow - How do i just load the data associated with a marker in google maps?

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

In flutter flow I have an app with markers on a google maps. When a marker is tapped a bottom sheet containing and audio player and an image associated with the location.

The data is fetched from firebase using a query for the page. Since there are a lot of markers, **how can i make sure that the audio files are only loaded when a marker is tapped?**

I was thinking i could have to collections on with location and ID, and one with ID and the audio files that could be loaded with the bottom sheet. Haven successfully created it where they share the data/IDs